# TCP - Possible to send data without active listener?

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming

Is it possible for client side to send data to a TCP port, to then later collect using a listener, or does the TCP in all cases need an active listener to even send the information?

The idea is to use TCP as an email alternative, i.e to send using client TCP program and receive using listener.

Comment: Something needs to be listening at the remote socket you are sending to, yes. That's the case for any kind of tcp/ip socket-based connection (no matter if it's a raw socket or using some higher-level protocol within it). Your question, if I've understood it correctly, seems to be analogous to "can I throw a ball at somebody when they're not looking and still expect them to catch it?".

Comment: I appreciate the response. My question was more meant like a "Can i throw my ball into a basket and then have someone pick it up when they need it later", but i guess that's not TCP then

Comment: Any information sent before listener appears is lost. So no, whatever you've send won't be magically hold *somewhere* for you. Email server stores data in database, so you can retrieve it.

Comment: @Drax To continue the analogy, someone needs to catch the ball and then put it in the basket. You can't aim it yourself, in this case, because the basket has a lid on, to keep the contents safe :-). The catcher (TCP listener) and the basket (data store for later retrieval) are two separate parts of the server-side architecture.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You will need to have a Listener so that the TCP session can send the data in the first place.

While technically it's possible to send packets after the Listener has vanished (eg crashed), this results in those sent packets being lost and isn't really what you are looking for.

It's not technically possible to send data unless a TCP connection is established, for which you need a Client and Listener. This establishment feature is defined in the TCP Protocol and is often called a TCP handshake.